# Make predictions on on HuggingFace's BERT with Dropout on

Tags: huggingface-transformers, dropout

The default behavior of `Trainer(...)` in HuggingFace when evaluating model is disabling Dropout. Concretely, `y_pred` for `M` runs will be exactly the same

```py
for i in range(M):
    logits, labels, metrics = trainer.predict(tokenized_datasets["eval"])
    y_pred = np.argmax(logits, axis=2)
    ...
```

Now I am trying to apply Monte Carlo Dropout trick introduced [this this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44065/what-is-monte-carlo-dropout). This requires to turn the Dropout **on** while making predictions on the validation set.

I am wondering how I achieve this goal. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set only the dropout layers to training:

```py
from torch import nn

from transformers import BertModel

model= BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model.eval()

def apply_dropout(m):
    if type(m) == nn.Dropout:
        m.train()

model.apply(apply_dropout)
```

as recommended in the pytorch forums ([here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dropout-at-test-time-in-densenet/6738), [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/using-dropout-in-evaluation-mode/27721)).